# Get XML node with namespace in java

Tags: java, xml

I have the next XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" 
         xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
         xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
         xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2"
         xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
         xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
         xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2"
         xmlns:sac="urn:sunat:names:specification:ubl:peru:schema:xsd:SunatAggregateComponents-1"
         xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ext:UBLExtensions>
        <ext:UBLExtension>
            <ext:ExtensionContent>
                <!-- SOME CODE HERE -->
            </ext:ExtensionContent>
        </ext:UBLExtension>
        <ext:UBLExtension>
            <ext:ExtensionContent>
                <!-- I WANT TO GET THIS NODE -->
            </ext:ExtensionContent>
        </ext:UBLExtension>
    </ext:UBLExtensions>
```

How can I get this node? I've tried

```
Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_MY_XML));
NodeList nodes = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "UBLExtension");
```

but it returns an empty array. How can I do it?

Comment: Many thanks. This is the response. Can you answer to mark it as aswered? (Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### A - Demo Code

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class GetXMLNodeInJavaDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            File fXmlFile = new File("sampleFile.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

            dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            printByElementTagname(doc);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void printByElementTagname(Document doc) {
        NodeList nodes = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "UBLExtension");
        Node node;
        for(int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            node = nodes.item(i);
            System.out.println(node.getNodeName() + " : " + node.getTextContent().trim());
        }
    }

}
```

#### B - Sample File : sampleFile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" 
         xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
         xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
         xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2"
         xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
         xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
         xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2"
         xmlns:sac="urn:sunat:names:specification:ubl:peru:schema:xsd:SunatAggregateComponents-1"
         xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ext:UBLExtensions>
        <ext:UBLExtension>
            <ext:ExtensionContent>
                Some Code
            </ext:ExtensionContent>
        </ext:UBLExtension>
        <ext:UBLExtension>
            <ext:ExtensionContent>
                What you want
            </ext:ExtensionContent>
        </ext:UBLExtension>
    </ext:UBLExtensions>
</Invoice>
```

#### C - Sample Output

```
ext:UBLExtension : Some Code
ext:UBLExtension : What you want
```

Comment: @Giancarlo Ventura Granados Well I'll be happier if it really helps, you can give an upvote for it :)

Comment: I still can not upvote your response, I only have 13 rep points

Comment: @Giancarlo Ventura Not a problem, I didn't know there's such a mechanism I'm sorry. Welcome to the stack overflow :)

Comment: @Giancarlo Ventura Granados I've noticed :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the XML parser is namespace aware.

You should also make sure to close the `FileInputStream`, preferably using try-with-resources.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);

Document doc;
try (InputStream xmlStream = new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_MY_XML)) {
    doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(xmlStream);
}
NodeList nodes = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "UBLExtension");
```

Comment: Many thanks, this is the response. 
I still can not give you points , but I have marked as correct.

Comment: It is also better to actually specify the namespace, rather than using wildcard. Define a `static final String` constant, e.g. `EXT_NS = "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"`, and use it in place of `"*"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to work with xpath

```
public static NodeList getNodesWithXPath(Node aNode, String aXPath) {
    try {
        XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression xPathExpression = xpath.compile(aXPath);
        return (NodeList) xPathExpression.evaluate(aNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        // ignore
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // ignore
    }
    return null;
}
```